# Does Hunger Games Count as Science Fiction?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm not sure, because even though hunger games is classified in the book as science fiction, I'm not sure if it's classified as off-topic here?

Comment: Do we need this question for every franchise?

Comment: The Hunger Games is more science fiction than is Star Wars.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Yes.

**Setting:**
[Post Apocalyptic future](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/thehungergames/images/4/42/Panem_map.png/revision/latest?cb=20140126041646)

**Technology:**
[Holographic flaming transforming dresses](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hLbmbVxhHAs)
[Force Fields](http://thehungergames.wikia.com/wiki/Force_field)
[Free-standing Holograms](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/thehungergames/images/8/86/Mockingjay2-still6.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20150819161041)

**Marketing**:

> ***We’re in a fictional world, a science fiction world**, and it’s very
> easy - it would have been very easy - to sort of pull back and kind of
> use the world and the stylized sense of it all to keep all the
> realities at arm’s length. But instead, with the actors and the
> locations we chose - every aspect of our approach in the filmmaking
> was to try and find the honest version of this.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Director Francis Lawrence On THE HUNGER GAMES: MOCKINGJAY - PART 1](http://birthmoviesdeath.com/2014/11/20/the-badass-interview-director-francis-lawrence-on-the-hunger-games-mockingj)</sup></sub>

and

> ***Is it an action-heavy role?***
>
> *“No. I actually see it more as a drama, with action in it. It’s a very sad story about this girl who’s forced into doing this in this world where the rich watch children die as entertainment. It’s gripping and it’s urgent. It’s a terrible world. It’s actually not far off from reality. We live in a world where humanity is becoming so desensitised to violence and to tragedy that peoples’ tragedy is our entertainment. **We’re obsessed with reality television and we get so numb to violence, tragedy, that it takes more to shock us, and more and more. It’s not that science-fiction, if you think about it. ”***
>
> <sub><sup>[The Hunger Games Interview 4: Jennifer Lawrence](http://www.gamesradar.com/the-hunger-games-interview-4-jennifer-lawrence/)</sup></sub>

Comment: Dammit, your second link roped me into spending 15 minutes watching *Catching Fire* clips on Youtube! It's worse than TV Tropes.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/TheHungerGamesCatchingFire

Answer (score 6):

### Yes.

The *Hunger Games* books and films are definitely on-topic here. We have over 100 questions about them, including [some very well-received ones](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108633/does-katniss-depict-proper-handling-of-a-bow).

Comment: this logic doesn't always hold. See "programming on a boat" :)

Comment: @DVK Sure, but that was the easy way of answering this question. I left Valorum to do the legwork of composing a more detailed answer ;-)